# Seg fault when launching Civ 6 in Steam, Ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, steam, segmentation-fault

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04.3 (64-bit) and Steam. When trying to launch Civilization 6 I'm getting the following error:

```
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingShaderCache with ""
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Opted-in Controller Mask: 0
Game update: AppID 289070 "", ProcID 12076, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 12076 for game ID 289070
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 289070, ActionID 1] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
Generating new string page texture 139: 256x256, total string texture memory is 1.46 MB
>>> Adding process 12077 for game ID 289070
Game update: AppID 289070 "", ProcID 12078, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 289070
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197997710598 [API loaded no]
>>> Adding process 12078 for game ID 289070
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 289070 "", ProcID 12078 
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1513371133)
Generating new string page texture 141: 256x256, total string texture memory is 393.22 KB
Generating new string page texture 143: 8x256, total string texture memory is 1.47 MB
Generating new string page texture 144: 16x256, total string texture memory is 1.48 MB
Generating new string page texture 145: 24x256, total string texture memory is 1.51 MB
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue? Here are my system specs:

```
Computer Information:
    Manufacturer:  Unknown
    Model:  Unknown
    Form Factor: Laptop
    No Touch Input Detected

Processor Information:
    CPU Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Brand:        Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x2a
    CPU Stepping:  0x7
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  3100 Mhz
    8 logical processors
    4 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Supported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported
    AES:  Supported
    AVX:  Supported
    CMPXCHG16B:  Supported
    LAHF/SAHF:  Supported
    PrefetchW:  Unsupported

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  4.13.0-26-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  11905000
    X Window Manager:  Compiz
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime-beta-release_2017-10-05

Video Card:
    Driver:  NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GTX 570M/PCIe/SSE2
    Driver Version:  4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.111
    OpenGL Version: 4.5
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 60 Hz
    VendorID:  0x10de
    DeviceID:  0x1210
    Revision Not Detected
    Number of Monitors:  2
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1920 x 1080
    Desktop Resolution: 3840 x 1080
    Primary Display Size: 20.91" x 11.77" (23.98" diag)
                                            53.1cm x 29.9cm (60.9cm diag)
    Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
    Primary VRAM: 1536 MB
    Supported MSAA Modes:  2x 4x 8x 16x 

Sound card:
    Audio device: Realtek ALC892

Memory:
    RAM:  16018 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    LANG:  en_CA.UTF-8
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  147009 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  110410 Mb
    VR Headset: None detected

Recent Failure Reports:
```

Comment: Your processor doesn't meant the minimum specfiications for Civ 6

Comment: And neither does the GPU. Please check system requirements before installing and trying to run any software. That way you won't be surprised when it doesn't run in a machine way below the requirements.

Comment: @MichaelBay It runs fine on Windows. I was installing in on Linux as a way to play with a friend with the Mac version. Linux gaming FTW

Comment: Again please check the system requirements which are noticeably different: http://store.steampowered.com/app/289070/Sid_Meiers_Civilization_VI/ (click Windows for Windows requirements and SteamOS+Linux for Ubuntu requirements) Games coded for DirectX have often higher requirements when ported to OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

> When trying to launch Civilization 6 I'm getting the following error:

Your system does not meet the minimum specifications for the game.

> - Minimum: 1 GB & AMD 5570 or nVidia 450
> - Intel Core i3 2.5 Ghz or AMD Phenom II 2.6 Ghz or greater

[Source](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri/requirements/civilization-6/13429)

Comment: I can run it on Windows, thought I'd be able to get away with it :(